# Creating boolean raster using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, boolean

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I try to perform a Boolean analysis (0 and 1 value) and I am stuck at a problem. I will mention the steps I did, first to get an idea.

I have multiple vector layers.

I created a buffer around those vectors, based on criteria.

I converted the resulted buffers to raster layers.

I reclassified each of the buffer rasters to a value of 0 (unsuitable)

This gave me multiple reclassified rasters with a only value of 0.

I want to stack these rasters in raster calculator to give me a single raster with values of 0 where the input rasters have 0 and a value of 1 outside the unsuitable area.

When I multiplied 3 or more of the input rasters I get an empty raster output.

For example, I have a vector layer of houses only (polygon shape). I need to set up a buffer distance of 200m around houses. The buffer I created, I converted it to raster, and then I set the value of '0' because this area is not suitable. I don't have any polygons to set to 1.

How do I stack these rasters to give me a single raster with values of 0 where the input rasters have 0 and a value of 1 outside the unsuitable area?

Comment: Your reclassified rasters likely have values of 0 or NoData.  Any ArcGIS operation that involves NoData returns NoData.  For example, 0 * NoData = NoData.  Reclassify your rasters so that 0 = 0 and NoData = 1.  Try your map arithmetic again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the [Cell Statistics (Spatial Analyst)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cell-statistics.htm) tool. Use the maximum or minimum statistic and ensure Ignore NoData in calculations is checked. You'll now have an output raster of all the 0's and NoData
2. In the raster calculator use an expression like `IsNull("output of previous step")`. You'll now have an output raster of all the 0's and NoData replaced by 1's.